# Insert Object entries into database with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, object, pdo

**The Situation:**

I have an Object which was transferred via AJAX to my PHP File which should insert one or more lines into my database.

In the PHP file I use json_decode to make my object work in PHP

```
$insertDatesArray = json_decode($_REQUEST['insertDatesArray']);
```

When I output this Object I get this in PHP:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (4) {
  ["alterstufe"]=>
  array(3) {
   [0]=>    string(1) "1"
   [1]=>    string(1) "1"
   [2]=>    string(1) "1"
  }  
  ["sunday"]=>
  array(3) {
   [0]=>    string(10) "14.09.2014"
   [1]=>    string(10) "21.09.2014"
   [2]=>    string(10) "28.09.2014"
  }
  ["help1"]=>
  array(3) {
   [0]=>    string(1) "6"
   [1]=>    string(1) "7"
   [2]=>    string(1) "8"
  }  
["help2"]=>
  array(3) {
   [0]=>    string(1) "7"
   [1]=>    string(1) "8"
   [2]=>    string(1) "6"
  }
}
```

This is the code, which generates my Object:

```
var date = new Array();
var alterstufen = new Array();
var helpperson1 = new Array();
var helpperson2 = new Array();
var elems2 = $('#plan tbody tr');
var count2 = elems2.length;
$('#plan tbody tr').each(function(){    
    alterstufen.push($('.pp-age').val());
    date.push($('#pp-service-date', this).val());
    helpperson1.push($('.selector-help1', this).val());
    helpperson2.push($('.selector-help2', this).val());
});
var days = new Object();
days.alterstufe = alterstufen;
days.sunday = date;
days.help1 = helpperson1;
days.help2 = helpperson2;
var insertDatesArray = JSON.stringify( days );
```

**The plan:**

Now what I should have is this:

I need to insert every row (with one value from every object property) into my Database via PHP::PDO
Right now i stuck at how I can set variables for every value.

My code looks like this right now:

```
foreach ($insertDatesArray as $obj => $val) {
   $alterstufe = $val->alterstufe;
   $date = $val->date;
}
```

**The problem:**

I don't know, how I can get the value from each object property to set them together and insert the data into my database.

Comment: You can do this from the server side, but it might be a little convoluted. It would be more elegant to change whatever is generating your JSON object to use a better object structure. Can we see the code generating the object?

Comment: @gandaliter I added the information to show how the object is generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
$entriesCount = count($insertDatesArray->alterstufe);

for($i = 0; $i < $entriesCount; ++$i) {
    var_dump($insertDatesArray->alterstufe[$i]);
    var_dump($insertDatesArray->sunday[$i]);
    var_dump($insertDatesArray->help1[$i]);
    var_dump($insertDatesArray->help2[$i]);

    // execute your query here with the data above
}
```

But as the first comment below your question tells you it's probably easier and cleaner to change the client side part.

So I would change the JS part instead to:

```
var data = new Array();

$('#plan tbody tr').each(function(){    
    data.push({
        alterstufen: $('.pp-age').val()
        date: $('#pp-service-date', this).val(),
        help1: $('.selector-help1', this).val(),
        help2: $('.selector-help2', this).val()
    });
});
```

Then you get a nice all-in-one package at server side.

Comment: I added the information to show how the object is generated

Comment: your first code snippet: is this compatible with your second code snippet?

Comment: No if you use your structure from the question then use the first snippet. If you change the structure like I suggested in the second snippet use your `foreach` code snippet in your question.

Comment: THANKS! Works now. PS: Simmer beidi vode Schwiiz gell?

Comment: @ismaelw Gseht fascht so uus, ja ;-)